# Dimension of Global Sections of Zero Dimensional Subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a proper one dimensional scheme over $k$ (so over a Noetherian ring). Consider a finite discrete closed subscheme $D \subset X$. By definition $D = \{d_1, d_2, ..., d_n \}$ and for the induced structure sheaf of $D$ we obviously have $H^0(D, \mathcal{O}_D) = \oplus _{d_i} \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}$.

My questions are:

1. Why does $\dim_k H^0(D, \mathcal{O}_D) = \dim_k \oplus _{d_i} \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i} = \sum _{d_i} \operatorname{length} \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}$ hold? Expecially over which ring $R$ we interpret each $\mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}$ as a $R$-module by considering the module length? Over $R =k$?
2. Why $X$ must be reduced if we want that $\dim_k \oplus _{d_i} \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i} = \sum _{d_i} [k(d_i): k]$ holds? Can't we always lift the dimension $[k(d_i): k]$ of $k(d_i)$ as $k$ vector space by Nakayama to the the $k$-dimension of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}$?

My ideas to 1.:
That's clear that $\dim_k \oplus _{d_i} \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i} = \sum _{d_i} \dim_k  \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i} $ and furthermore for every $k$ vector space $V$ we have $\dim_k V = \operatorname{length}_k V$ with $V$ as $k$ module.

So I can reduce the claim to the proof that $\operatorname{length}_k  \mathcal{O}_{X, d_i} =\operatorname{length}_{\mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}}  \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}$ must hold. Why?
Remark: Using A.Rod's hint I mean $\operatorname{length}\mathcal{O}_{D, d_i} = \operatorname{length}_{\mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}} \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}$ so considering $\mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}$ as a $\mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}$-module.

Comment: 1. The length is over the ring itself. It is Artin and thus has finite length.

Comment: 2. Nakayama tells you that a spanning set can be lifted to a spanning set. But for having equality of the dimension you need more.

Comment: @A.Rod: Thank you for the answer. Do you have a good reference where is proved\explained that $dim_k \oplus _{d_i} \mathcal{O}_{X, d_i} = \sum _{d_i} length \ \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}$ holds?

Comment: I don't have time to expand now, but I re-read your post. And there must be some mistakes/typo sprinkled here and there. For instance $O_{X,d_i}$ is not a finite $k$-algebra, I guess you mean $O_{D,d_i}$, don't you?

Comment: I feel like essentially what you need is that if $M$ is finite-length module over a ring $R$ then $lg_R(M)=\sum_{p_i} lg_{R_{p_i}}(M_{p_i}) $ the sum being taken over max ideals of $R$, which follows directly from localizing a chain giving you the length.

Comment: Firstly, yes sorry I meant indeed $\mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}$. My concering is the following: $\oplus _{d_i} \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}$ is here considered as $k$ vector space, isn't it? The $\mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}$ inherit ´the $k$ vector space structure, don't they? So $dim_k \oplus _{d_i} \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}= \sum _{d_i} dim_k \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}$. Futhermore for every $k$ vector space $V$ holds $dim_k V = length_k V$ if you consider $V$ as $k$ module, right? This would imply that $dim_k \oplus _{d_i} \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}= \sum _{d_i} dim_k \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}= \sum length_k \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}$.

Comment: But this would contradict $dim_k \oplus _{d_i} \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i} = \sum _{d_i} length \ \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}$ if one consider by $ length \ \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i} = length_{\mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}} \ \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}$ as length of the stalk concidered as module over the ring itself, because I suppose that $ length_{\mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}} \ \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i} \neq length_k \mathcal{O}_{D, d_i}$. Where is my error in the reasoning?

Comment: You're right... the correct formula should be $\dim_k H^0(D, O_D)=\sum_{d_i}[k(d_i):k] length_{O_{D,d_i}} O_{D, d_i}$.
Indeed $\dim_k H^0(D, O_D)=\sum_{d_i} \dim_{k} O_{D, d_i}=\sum_{d_i}length_{k} O_{D, d_i}=\sum_{d_i}[k(d_i):k] length_{O_{D,d_i}} O_{D, d_i}$.
The last equality follows from the fact that if $A\to B$ is a local morphism (between local rings)  then $length_A(M)=[B/m_B:A/m_A] length_B M$ which is obvious because if $M$ is an $R$-module killed by an ideal $I$ then $lg_{R/I}M=lg_R M$